# Quotes around non-technical terms?

Tags: quotation-marks

I'm editing some technical papers that use industry specific terms but also common phrases and sets them in quotation marks.

> Examples: 
>   We will provide the client a two week "look ahead" regarding
>   project status.
>
> We will hold "brainstorming" sessions.
>
> As a result of our "risk workshops" we were able to allay the clients'
>   fears.

Interestingly, there are no quotes around more technical terms such as WBS (work breakdown schedule). Or CPM (critical path method).

Is this use of quotation marks okay or should I remove them?
My inclination is to remove them.

Comment: The author simply felt that these terms were jargon, and thus wanted to set them apart.  It's a style issue, and in some cases you might leave some and remove others.

Comment: I get what you mean. They're not really jargon though, they're kind of quasi-jargon. The actual technical terms are written out with they initialisms.

Comment: "Jargon" doesn't necessarily mean elements of the quasi-official argot of a particular occupation or industry.  The term "look ahead", although probably not in any dictionary in this sense, in business means a conscious process of considering future activities.  Specific nuances would be applied to this phrase by particular businesses or industries.  The quotes simply signal that such an idiomatic meaning is intended, vs literally interpreting the two words separately.

Comment: Similarly with "risk workshops", this is presumably a meaningful phrase in this context.  Likely "brainstroming" is being quoted simply for consistency with the others, though, since it's recognizable on its own.

Comment: I see what you mean. I would like our internal style to direct us to avoid these types of quotes. I think it looks odd on the page and there's also a bit of a slippery slope argument as there are probably a dozen more terms that fall on the same line as those above. I think it is also being used inconsistently e.g.: "The firm "stands ready" to assist [Client] with their engineering needs." and "We can provide [client] with a single "go-to" point of contact for all issues."  What do you think about eschewing this use of quotation marks?

Comment: That's up to you.  I just wanted you to understand the likely purpose behind the practice.  You decide if it's justified in your cases.